# Where can i find my STORE_UUID for Uber Eats?

Tags: uber-api

I'm trying to make a link open the app directly at the restaurant. I found this deep link for that:

```
ubereats://store/browse?client_id=eats&storeUUID={STORE_UUID}
```

However, I can't find the {STORE_UUID} to replace. Looked everywhere. Nothing. Where can I find it?

Thanks in advance.